# php include function to include parent folder in LAMP server

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, lamp

im developing a MVC app in php using wamp & codeigniter in windows 7. the app works without any issue.

i'm totally new to linux and ubuntu.

but i need to host this in ubuntu linux machine. i have used `<php include ('/../footer.php); ?>` in windows wamp and it's working.

once i upload to ubuntu lamp. i'm getting `include ('/../footer.php) failed to open stream`

i tried searching in the net but couldnt get a solution.

how to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the leading `/` and change your includes to

```
 include("../footer.php");
```

the leading / means from the root of the file system.

You are digging below the root and there just ain't nothing there.

Another thing to beware of when dealing with problems between windows and linux is that on windows ../footer.php is the same as ../Footer.php which is not the case on linux (case sensitive vs case insensitive file systems).

**UPDATE**

The final solution was to for the relative path for the include into a absolute one by prefixing it with `__DIR__` as in ...

```
include(__DIR__."/../footer.php");
```

Comment: where is footer.php relative to your gateway script (the index.php that gets rewritten to). and make sure that it's called footer.php and not called Footer.php

Comment: the spelling is correct. is lower case `footer.php`. the `footer.php` file in `views` folder the calling file is in `views/auth/` folder

Comment: generally at the root of your application there is an index.php file that all of your requests get rewritten to. In the context of a request all of the relative include paths will be relative to this location. (the location of that gateway script)

Comment: and would the footer.php be in the views folder?

Comment: try changing the include to `include(__DIR__."/../footer.php");`

Comment: yes that did the magic... now its working.. so i need to change all places where i have to include as above.

Comment: Would probably be the most portable solution.

Comment: The difference is that your lamp version probably has `.` in the include path, which many feel is insecure

Comment: pls update your answer so i can accept that. it'll give a clear picture without reading the comments.. :-)